# Can I use a for loop to run a sample set through a user defined function?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I would like to run a randomly selected sample (from a larger dataset) of n size through a function `B` number of times.

This is what I have so far...

```
estimates <- function(vctr){
  e.mean <- mean(vctr); e.var <- var(vctr) 
  return(c(a = e.mean^2/e.var, s = e.var/e.mean))
}

est.loop <- function(df, n, B){
    rand.sample <- sample(df, n)
    return(rand.sample)
}
new.est <- est.loop(df, n=100)
estimates(new.est)
```

```
     for(rand.sample in B){
      estimates(rand.sample)
    }
  }
```

I know this is incomplete but some help getting the `for` loop correct to run the `rand.sample` through `other.function`, `B` number of times would be very much appreciated.

Note: when I run `other.function(rand.sample)` outside of the loop, it works as intended. I just need to get it to repeat now using an input for `B` when calling `my.function`.

Thank you!!

EDIT: Function `estimates` returns the desired output of `a` and `s` values. `estimates(new.est)` works exactly as I would like (output `a` and `s` values for the new dataset of `n` size). What I would like to do is repeat this `B` times within `est.loop` to create an array of `a` and `s` values.

Comment: Are you trying to print the output of `other.function(rand.sample)`? Or save it somewhere? If the former, try to change to `print(other.function(rand.sample))`. Beyond that, it may help us to answer you if you add some elements to make this reproducible (example dataset, example function, etc.)

Comment: It's difficult to say what your goal is here. Are you trying to re-sample your dataset in each iteration of the for loop? Or are you just getting the re-sampled dataset once? Either way, the for loop is not likely set up correctly, and I don't think you are resampling correctly.

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to print the output of `other.function(rand.sample)` as an array. Without any repeats, `other.function` produces two values (what I want) but I would now like to repeat this to get `B` number of the two-value vector. I will add elements/specificity to clarify. Thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: Maybe `res <- lapply(seq_len(B), function(i) other.function(rand.sample))`. Then the function returns `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following does what the question asks for.
Tested with built-in data set `iris`.

```
estimates <- function(df){
  f <- function(vctr){
    e.mean <- mean(vctr)
    e.var <- var(vctr) 
    c(a = e.mean^2/e.var, s = e.var/e.mean)
  }
  sapply(df, f)
}

est.loop <- function(df, n, B){
  i <- sample(nrow(df), n)
  rand.sample <- df[i, ]
  lapply(seq_len(B), function(i) estimates(rand.sample))
}

df <- iris[-5]

est.loop(df, n = 100, B = 3)
```